# Can't create my sql table from php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create an sql table with php and I keep getting the following error Table creation failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7. I have my php opening they are just farther up the screen

```
if(!$mysqli->query("CREATE Table VSTORE(
id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL Unique,
category VARCHAR(255),
length INT unsigned,
rented boolean NOT NULL default 0,
);
")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: get rid of the comma on line 6 after the `0` and the semicolon on line 7

Comment: I got rid of the comma but kept the semicolon as i saw the comment late and it worked. Is not having a semicolon correct syntax?

Comment: You use semicolons at the end of a statement. Since the statement isn't completed, you don't need the semicolon at that place.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last comma after "rented boolean NOT NULL default 0,"

It should be "rented boolean NOT NULL default 0"

Answer (score 0):

So just do any query in phpMyAdmin before you try to use it in the code.
That helps a lot:

```
if(!$mysqli->query("CREATE Table VSTORE(
id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL Unique,
category VARCHAR(255),
length INT unsigned,
rented boolean NOT NULL default 0 );
")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```